# Replace the word "dent"

Tags: word-request

> If you touch a balloon there is a **dent** created at your finger tip.

Now this word *dent* seems so rough. Like one has to use a lot of pressure to create a dent. Is there any proper word to replace it so the sentence seems like one doesnt have to use that much pressure at all.

Answer (score 6):

The first Merriam-Webster [definition of "dent"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dent) is

> Verb. 1: to make a dent in, dent a car.

This sounds pretty rough for a balloon, and is a verb, but further down they say

> Noun. 1: a depression or hollow made by a blow or by pressure.

So there is nothing wrong with using **a dent** to describe the depression in a balloon.

If you don't like the word **dent** you might accept **hollow** which seems more gentle (although it depends on how tightly the balloon was inflated). Another suggestion is **indentation** which also does not sound so "rough" as **dent**.

Answer (score 5):

A part of a surface that is lower than the rest can be said to be **depressed** or **indented**, and the area thus created can be called a **depression** or an **indentation**.

> depression noun (PRESS DOWN) ​ [ C ] a part in a surface that is
>   slightly lower than the rest:
>
> There was a depression in the sand where he'd been lying.

[Depression](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/depression)

> indentation noun (HOLE) ​ [ C ] a hole or mark on the surface of
>   something:
>
> The heels of her shoes had left indentations in the mud.

[Indentation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/indentation)

Slatter's Fundamentals of Veterinary Ophthalmology 5th Edition (2013, David Maggs, Paul Miller, Ron Ofri), page 99, gives a description, in ordinary educated language, of a technique used in animal and human medicine to measure the IOP (intra-ocular pressure) of an eyeball:

> Indentation Tonometry
>
> The Schiotz tonometer relies on indentation tonometry. In this method,
>   a standard force is applied with a metal rod to a topically
>   anesthetized cornea. The distance the rod indents the cornea is
>   measured and is inversely related to the LOP (i.e., the greater the
>   tonometer scale reading, the lower the patient's IOP). This concept is
>   easily understood if the eye is regarded as analogous to a
>   water-filled balloon. If the blunt end of a pencil is applied to the
>   balloon with a given force (e.g., the weight of the pencil placed
>   vertically), the pencil indents the surface of the balloon by a
>   certain distance. If the pressure in the balloon is decreased (some of
>   the water is let out), the tension in the rubber wall decreases, and
>   the same pencil resting on the balloon indents it farther. Conversely,
>   if the pressure in the balloon is increased, the same pencil indents
>   it less. The Schiotz tonometer (Figure 5-40) consists of three parts:
>   the plunger (analogous to the pencil), the footplate assembly (a
>   device to measure indentation), and the handle. A further refinement is added: The weight applied to the eye through the rod may be
>   varied by adding or subtracting weights (5.5 g, 7.5 g, 10 g, or 15 g).
>   The greater the weight applied to the eye at a given IOP, the greater
>   the penetration of the rod.

[Slatter's *Fundamentals*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8QCduRN3zR0C&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=indentation%20balloon&source=bl&ots=c0RKbMQaeG&sig=pSx3oLDFwfTnOVYq9o2cHrHG7q8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio-pWS_LXcAhUB9YMKHXWhBskQ6AEIVTAN)

Comment: "Dimple" also works, if it makes a long-lasting impression.

Comment: The depression exists while the balloon is being pressed, which accords with the original question. Also, an indentation is correct for a pressed balloon.

Comment: If you remove the pressure exerted by your fingertip on a balloon filled with air, no indentation remains.Ergo, indentation does not work here. Indentations remain on a surface after the fact; that's impossible for a balloon.

Comment: Who says indentations have to remain?

Comment: The definition in the dictionary: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indentation?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld  For instance: There were several small indentations in the surface of the table. Indentations are typically made in  hard surfaces. That is the basic semantic trait of an indentation for that meaning. [Don't shoot the messenger.]

Comment: "Don't shoot the messenger" - or poke him in the eye?

Comment: I  think most native speakers agree that  indentations are more permanent than not. I'm sorry that is upsetting to you.

Comment: Indentations can be of shorter or longer duration.

Answer (score 0):

**Soft surfaces**: depression, a lower spot that is made on a surface by a force, which may or may not remain when the force is removed. A finger would create a depression  on the surface of the balloon.

- pillow: indentation [it remains after you lift your head off of it]. Indentations remain when the pressure is removed. indentation on the surface of a freshly painted wall.
- balloon: depression, a depression is created by your finger and then fills out again when you remove your finger.
- Rock or wood: A hollow is left after the action of a force such as wind or rain since material is removed when there is a hollow. A hollow log: has no wood at its center. It has been eroded by water or bugs or time or a knife or I-don't-know what.
- wood table, metal objects etc: Cars bumpers are easily dented. A dent is made on a hard surface, not a soft one. Some plastics can be dented too.
- the ground: a depression: there is a depression in the grass.

Different terms are  used for hard and soft surfaces, and they are not 100% interchangeable. I have given above the most usual which came to (my) mind.

Answer (score 0):

There's numerous examples on [this website](https://wikidiff.com/dent/bump) but a few that stick out are:

> Dent: "A shallow deformation in the surface of an object, produced by an impact."

Also

> Bump: "A protuberance on a level surface."

If you read further on the website I think it can be seen that either word would be used appropriately quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you touch a balloon lightly enough, it may not create a dent *at all*—but it could still leave a mark on it, such as a fingerprint, dirt, or other visible sign. (Also, any dent created will be quite temporary and disappear as soon as you remove your finger.)

A word that captures both an ephemeral dent *and* any other sign of having touched it once your finger is removed is [**impression**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impression):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **2** : the effect produced by impressing: such as
>   **a** : a stamp, form, or figure resulting from physical contact
>
> **3** : the act of impressing: such as
>   **a** : an affecting by stamping or pressing
>
> [[impressing]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impressing)
>
> **1 a** : to apply with pressure so as to imprint
>   **b** : to produce (something, such as a mark) by pressure
>   **c** : to mark by or as if by pressure or stamping